# Stability condition of a finite difference algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, stability

While studying finite difference methods of TDSE I found myself stuck on a reasoning step:

> The largest possible spatial curvature for the wave function, $\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} \Psi(x, t)$, will occur if the wave function changes from one peak to the neighbor peak across a distance 2Δx.
>   This implies that $\left|\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} \Psi(x, t)\right|<\left|\frac{\Psi(x, t)}{(\Delta x)^{2}}\right|$.

(This is Equation 11 on this [page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/www.numfys.net/media/notebooks/one_dimensional_wave_propagation.ipynb).)

How does one explain this implication?

Comment: There is a different way to think about this which might help. (I can't be bothered to work through the details in your reference!) In one time step of the numerical solution, a disturbance at one grid point can only propagate to the nearest grid point on either side. For a given $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$, that means there is a maximum propagation speed in the finite difference solution. If the "exact" solutions of the *differential equation* propagate *faster* than that velocity, the numerical results can not represent the physics, and usually the numerical solution diverges to infinity.

Comment: … Since you usually choose $\Delta x$ to capture the spatial resolution of the solution, the way to *increase* the numerical "propagation speed" $\Delta x / \Delta t$ is to *decrease* $\Delta t$.